# Caching issue in uiautomator

Tags: android-testing, android-uiautomator

I have an android app. I am doing automated testing of this app using uiautomator.
Before doing any processing I need to login the app. But at first time it store the data in cache and login automatically every time when I launch.

I want application should be logged in every time with filled credential.

Is there any way to stop this caching by using uiautomator api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio -- clear application data for Instrumentation Test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713579/android-studio-clear-application-data-for-instrumentation-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give below command before you start your tests, this would clear you application data. Then start your tests !

```
adb shell pm clear yourPackageName
```

Comment: Can we run more than one test cases by a single command using uiautomator ?

Comment: Unfortunately NO... but can check below framework, Ive not tested it personally though.. http://sourceforge.net/projects/uiautomator/

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Even on a basic note, someone can see that any shell script can be automated. Typing a command in every time you need to cache bust is a bad suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.. Did I say we can't automate it ? :)..  I just gave a pointer to address the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who wants to clear your target app under test, while running UiAutomator, you could probably try the method I wrote below. This only works with API level 18 or greater.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html#executeShellCommand(java.lang.String)

```
public static void clearData (String packageName) {

    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation()
                    .executeShellCommand("pm clear " + packageName)
                    .close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: when i try this with the latest Uiautomator 2.0 i get:  INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713579/android-studio-clear-application-data-for-instrumentation-test

Answer (score 0):

In your app you can manually first clear the data or disable the "Save my credential" option in the app. So every time when starting the app it will ask for the credentials again.

Or else you can directly write it in command prompt before running the test case.

```
adb shell pm clear yourPackageName
```