# Gradle, sending command to adb

Tags: android, gradle

I need that every time before running the tests, run the task with the command for `adb`

`adb shell pm reset-permissions`

I tried doing this in my gradle file, it`s compilling, but how does it run?

```
buildscript {
...
}

android {
...
}

task resetPermission(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'adb', 'shell', 'pm', 'reset-permissions'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to edit your test running configurations, to add the task.

See my (similar) answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35157119/4706693

Comment: Thanks! Thank you very very much!!