# How to clean application data with 'pm clear' after each UI test

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-uiautomator, ui-testing

I started writing UI tests in android using Espresso Framework and UI Automator.

So I wrote 3 different UI tests, all of them containing the authentication process. When I run each test individually they are working just fine.
But, when I run all 3 tests using `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`, the first test passes and the other 2 tests fail, because it auto logins (I use webview for login so it redirects me to main screen). I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597080/reset-app-state-between-instrumentationtestcase-runs) but it didn't work.

What I want to archive is, after each test, to clear the data using
`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("pm clean com.example.app")` and have a fresh start for each test.

when I execute this in @After, the tests crashes:

```
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.''.
```

Any Idea how I can archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to use [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator), since it will run each test in a separate process, which means that no state or data is shared with other tests.