# [TEST][Espresso] Can not get element in RecycleView with more than one condition

Tags: java, android, testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

I trying to do automation test on android application with Espresso & Java and I want to input text into **base_input_view_input** in RecycleView
in which text of **base_input_view_title** equal "First name" with layout inspector as bellow:

[image: Like this]

I tried with this solution but it not work.

```
onView(withId(R.id.rvBasicInfo))
.perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem(allOf(withId(R.id.base_input_view_input),allOf(withId(R.id.base_input_view_title),withText("First name"))),typeText("aaaa")));
```

Here is the log

```
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll RecyclerView to: holder with view: (view.getId() is
<2131296360/com.test.a.vvv.app.ccc.ccc:id/base_input_view_input> and (view.getId() is
  <2131296362> and an instance of android.widget.TextView and view.getText() with or without transformation to match: is "First name"))' on view 'RecyclerView{id=2131296919, res-name=rvBasicInfo, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1595, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true,
    has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@eb7851f, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false,
    has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=7}'.
```

Please help me to correct the code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your matcher is not selecting the correct element. You are currently trying to select an element that has an Id of `base_input_view_input` and is an element that has an Id of `base_input_view_title` with the text `First name`. Obviously, that wouldn't work, since the element you want doesn't have two different Ids! Instead, we should focus on parent/child/sibling relationships between the elements.

For me, it is helpful to pick the most specific part (usually an ID), and work backwards to identify what makes this element *truly unique*.

```
allOf(
  withId(R.id.base_input_view_input), 
  isDescendantOfA(
    allOf(
      withId(R.id.relInputView), 
      hasSibling(
        allOf(
          withId(R.id.base_input_view_title), 
          withText("First name")
        )
      )
  )
)
```

(Parentheses might be off on that...)

I've set up the line breaks to show what level of matching they are at, since things are a little confusing.
We want to find:

- an element with the Id of `base_input_view_input`
- AND is a descendant of an element which has...

  - an Id of `relInputView`
  - AND has a sibling with an element...

    - with an Id of `base_input_view_title`
    - AND has the text of `First name`

Since you have multiple elements with the Id of `base_input_view_input`, we need something more specific. If the next thing that makes this unique is that it's parent element (`R.id.relInputView`) has a sibling with specific text (in this case, `First name`), then we should check for an element that has those.

You could also abstract this matcher into a function to more easily re-use it for when the `base_input_view_title` has different text.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support! I tried with your suggestion and it's worked!

Comment: No problem! I find it is usually easier to get the specific view and then work my way up/down the other views in the layout inspector.

Comment: I have one more question:
I have a robot keyword (Keyword in Robot Framework) to call API to create new Customer 
Can I call this keyword in Espresso test case ?

Comment: Sorry @Sarah, I don't have significant enough experience with the Robot Framework to answer that.

Comment: Thank you @agoff. I found the solution for it

Comment: HI @agoff, I have one more quesstion.  I want to reset application or clean cache of application before/after run my espresso test cases. How can I do that?

Comment: On my current app, we use `testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: true` in the `build.gradle`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713579/android-studio-clear-application-data-for-instrumentation-test/57461180#57461180